# Getting pytest to understand exec built-in function

Tags: python, pytest, python-exec

I have a simple test below that I run with `pytest`.  It works via the built-in function [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

```py
def test_exec() -> None:
    foo = ""  # Causes test to fail if not updated by exec
    exec("foo = 5")
    assert isinstance(foo, int)
```

When run outside of `pytest` (via `ipython`), the code works fine.  When run via `pytest`, the `exec` statement doesn't seem to be run properly.

How can I run an `exec` function as part of a `pytest`?

---

**Versions**

```
Python==3.8.5
pytest==6.1.1
```

Comment: Why are you using `exec`? Do you understand that `exec` cannot modify local variables? Just don't use `exec`, there is *almost certainly* a better way. This question really has nothing to do with `pytest`.

Comment: Needless to say, I had some fundamental misunderstandings on `exec`. The duplicate question pointed me to figuring out the problem.  @juanpa.arrivillaga the code in my question was just a minimal repro.  You're right, it turns out not to have anything to do with `pytest`